# Control event not firing inside ItemTemplate

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, events

I have a website in which I have a checkout register with dynamically cretaed row for each ordered item. And on each row there is a checkbox and when the checkbox is checked I want to update the underlying class and set the a boolean property. The problem is that the OnCheckedChanged event is not firing.

The ItemTemplate:

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <div>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="CheckBox1_OnCheckedChanged"/>
    </div>
</ItemTemplate>
```

The code-behind event:

```
protected void CheckBox1_OnCheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Handle event
}
```

I have found a few people with similar problems but none of the solutions I've found have worked.
The most popular solution was to set AutoPostBack="true", which I have and still nothing.
I'd really appreciate some guidance.

**EDIT**

I can add that I've now tried using a button in a similar fasion. The buttons OnClick event fires without problem while the checkbox still won't work.

**EDIT 2**

Just for fun I added a button next to the checkbox which i connected to an empty event. When the button was pressed and the checkbox had changed value the OnCheckedChanged event happened. I guess because the button caused a postback. But why doesn't checkbox cause a postback? Shouldn't it with AutoPostBack="true"??

Answer (score 0):

i think your event is wrong.

```
protected void CheckBox1_OnCheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Handle event
}
```

Comment: Oh sorry! That is just a mistake I made when trying to rename things for the post. Fixed now.